# What is the actual use of the optional host parameter and optional callback in the app.listen() method in Nest JS?

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, nestjs-config, nestjs-swagger

In the main.ts file in Nest JS, the following bootstrap function contains the app.listen() method.

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

My question is what is the actual use of the following parameters:

- hostname: string,
- callback?: () => void

specially that the listenAsync is deprecated and the current .listen() method can be awaited, so why will I ever use the callback that is executed when the server is running.

Comment: look at the source here: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/6363cbe29d131f54361adf6e0a3367253345b255/packages/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.ts#L132-L134

Comment: @MicaelLevi, I looked at it, but still can't understand when to use the callback...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the fastify adapter and docker, you need to specify the host as `0.0.0.0` so that docker and fastify can communicate properly. Otherwise it'll only run on `127.0.0.1` which isn't *quite* right. As for the callback, *sometimes* fastify can throw an exception that isn't bubbled up completely, so the optional callback can help with debugging what is being thrown

Comment: Thanks, the first point is clear, but regarding the second point ... isn't this callback triggered when the server is successfully listening? and it has no parameters + it is void ...
I think that it's there because the old listenAsync is deprecated.

Comment: The callback does have parameters [you can see it being called here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/6363cbe29d131f54361adf6e0a3367253345b255/packages/core/nest-application.ts#L272), but generally Nest has tried to make it to where you shouldn't need to worry about it